# Definition of Weinstein manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, complex-manifolds

I have the following definition for Weinstein manifolds in my lecture:

A Weinstein manifold is an exact symplectic manifold $(W, \omega= d \lambda)$, whose associated Liouville vector field is complete (i.e. the flow exists for all times) and gradient-like for a smooth exhausting function $f:W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now this confuses me, since $\omega = d \lambda$ means $0=[\omega] \in H^2(W)$, right? But for symplectic forms, it always holds that $[\omega]\neq 0$.

Also, it says that Stein manifolds give examples for Weinstein manifolds, but I can't see why, since Stein manifolds don't need to have a complex structure.

What is my mistake here?

Comment: For COMPACT symplectic manifolds $(M,\omega)$, it is true that $[\omega]\in H^{2}(M)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Oh well yes thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Answering just to get this off the unanswered page.  Community wiki because I did nothing.)

As studiosus mentions in the comments, it is true for closed (compact, no boundary) symplectic manifolds that $[w]\in H^2(M;\mathbb{R})$ is non-zero.  But in general, it can be the zero class.  Consider, for example, the symplectic form $\omega = dx\wedge dy$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I am not a symplectic geometer; maybe someone else can edit this to mention something about the case where $M$ is compact but has non-empty boundary.  Are symplectic manifolds studied in this case?  What boundary conditions are imposed on the sympletic form?  Do these boundary conditions imply $[\omega]\neq 0\in H^2(M;\mathbb{R})$?